# Trouble using a custom NSObject class to simplify repetitive code in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to store a REST connection model in a single object so that I don't keep having to use it over and over again. Here is the model I created:

```c
//RestModel.h
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@interface RestModel : NSObject{
    NSString* _baseUrl;
    NSString* _modelUrl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* modelUrl;

- (id)initWithModel:(NSString*)model;
- (NSDictionary*)getById:(NSInteger*)ident;
- (NSDictionary*)getAll;

@end

//RestModel.m
#import "RestModel.h"

@implementation RestModel

@synthesize modelUrl = _modelUrl;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _baseUrl = @"http://myRESTurl.com";
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithModel:(NSString*)model
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _baseUrl = @"http://myRESTurl.com";
        self.modelUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/", _baseUrl, model];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary*)HTTPRequest:(NSURL*)url
{
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if(!error){
        NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;

        [error release]; 
        [request release];

        return (NSDictionary*)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:responseData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSDictionary*)getById:(NSInteger*)ident
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.modelUrl, ident]];
    return [self HTTPRequest:url];
}

- (NSDictionary*)getAll
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.modelUrl]];
    return [self HTTPRequest:url];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_modelUrl release];
//    [_responseData release];
//    [_responseDict release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Edit: Now it isn't crashing, but my local NSDictionary has a count of 0. I'm calling the following in -viewDidLoad in my controller:

```c
RestModel* rm = [[RestModel alloc] initWithModel:@"user"];
self.dict = [rm getAll];
[rm release];
```

I planted NSLog of [self.dict count] throughout the controller. It is always 0. The RestModel rm is called, the functions are called (again more NSLogs), but no data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    [error release]; 
    [request release];
```

Those should be auto-released objects, as you got them by convenience methods, so releasing them explicitly will make your application crash.

Comment: Ok, it isn't crashing now, but my NSDictionary is empty. I'm loading at -viewDidLoad and even put a NSLog of the count of my NSDictionary -tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section and it comes out 0. Should I not release the RestModel? This is how I'm loading it in -viewDidLoad: RestModel* rm = [[RestModel alloc] initWithModel:@"user"]; self.dict = [rm getAll];
[rm release];

Comment: Nevermind, you nailed it! The count problem was my own fault. You rock.

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger isn't an object so it isn't necessary to pass it using NSInteger * and certainly you do not want to use the %@ format specifier.  Instead try this:

```
    - (NSDictionary*)getById:(NSInteger)ident
    {
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d", self.modelUrl, ident]];
        return [self HTTPRequest:url];
    }
```

Comment: This is true, even if getById is not used in the user provided example.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes it doesn't fix my overall problem, but I'm still new so these things are helpful!